# How to index into the channel.members list and take out the name? Closed

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to get the names of all the people in a voice channel, but the bot returns a list like so:

```
[<Member id=704069756717629472 name='Eedward' discriminator='8402' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=807690875802878003 name='lfg testing' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=3>>]
```

Is there any way I can take that "name" part out of the list? Or is there a better way to do something like this? This is my code:

```py
    @client.command()
    async def lfg(ctx, game, *,extra=None):
      if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name}, you need to connect to a voice channel first to use this command.")
        return
    
      else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        link = await channel.create_invite(max_age = 300)
        members = len(ctx.message.author.voice.channel.members)
        members1 = ctx.message.author.voice.channel.members
        max_ = channel.user_limit
        if max_ == 0:
          max_ = 'None'
        if max_ == 'None':
          p = f'{members}, No Limit'
        else:
          p = f"{members} out of {max_}"
        em = Embed(color=discord.Color.gold())
        em.add_field(name='LFG Request', value=f"**{ctx.author.mention} is looking for a group in voice channel `#{channel}`**:\n\n**Game: {game}**\n\n**Extra Info:** {extra}\n\n**Connected Users:**{(members1)} ({p})\n\n**VC Invite: [Click here to join]({link})**")
        em.set_footer(text=f'Type !lfg (message) to create this embed | This LFG request was made by {ctx.author.name}')
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Sorry if it's a bit hard to read, thanks in advance! :D (Btw I'm trying to display the names of the users in the vc in the "Connected Users" section of the embed)

Edit: I figured it out, for those who want the code, here it is:

```
    members = len(ctx.message.author.voice.channel.members)
    count = 0
    members1 = ""
    for _ in range(int(members)):
      members1 += f"{ctx.message.author.voice.channel.members[count].mention}"
      count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `.name` to the member. This should get the name from the member.

Comment: doesnt work but thanks anyway, i figured it out